# How to calculate CPU Load Average in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-4.0

I have been looking everywhere for a snippet of code that will calculate the load average.

Any Ideas, Snippets, or links are greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Jeffrey

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Use the Performance counter class.  Category = "Processor", Counter = "% Processor time".  Read it once a second.

Comment: I have tried the Performance Counter class, however, I am looking for a number like a linux machine produces for load average. I haven't been able to find any formulas to produce the load average number, what I have found is the wiki on load average, however, the math in there is a bit over my head, any ideas on how I can produce the load average number is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Process` class has some properties you can use for that (`TotalProcessorTime`, `UserProcessorTime`, ...).

Msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime.aspx